# Parsing simple value types in a generic way

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to parse values e.g. from `process.env` in a generic manner using TypeScript:

```
type SimpleType = string | number | boolean

function getEnv<T extends SimpleType>(name: string): T { 
  return process.env[name] as T
}
```

But the `as` keyword in TypeScript does not provide type conversion (like in C# for example).

Is there a generic way of doing this?

Comment: The runtime is not affected by types. As such, `getEnv<string>('foo')` _cannot_ execute different code than `getEnv<number>('foo')` at runtime.

Comment: On a side note, your current code [is TS-valid](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFMFsFcBsEMAu4DOoDkA7ADpUBLTFReWWUAAUQE9tVhMB7AE3FAFp2V4A3cd1j3SgAZowBOoRAAt8aVpEYAoGnVAAFcYwDGqNAF5QAb3CYeALmMBtANbhql4uMIBzALqPEzzC4C+vgG4lbUYiRFBsLV0UFEtNHT1QQxMzSyMACQBRABlsgHlLdAB1PIAlbIARdH8glVo2AGV8SGxYcAAVeqTQJ1dQAB9QTGhIACNwSUHRxkY2+ExakWhMbUR8UNAXcERMswAedogAD2RMZjQmlrbOugA+AApMeEhwT28XAEpLQ6NQJVBQOJttBxJgIlE9AA6Uw8KxPF5uUDwNDtJS+IA): it doesn't throw any TS error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903701/1541563) is great, but I would have taken a slightly different approach.

Since he's established that types have no bearing on runtime, we do need to pass type information in the form of a value, but that doesn't necessarily require a `switch` in this case.

The [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), and [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) constructors can all be called statically to cast any value to their respective primitive, so we can define a function where a static function is provided as the second parameter.

```
type SimpleType = string | number | boolean;

interface SimpleConstructor<T extends SimpleType> {
  (value: any): T;
}

function getEnv<T extends SimpleType>(name: string, cast: SimpleConstructor<T>): T { 
  return cast(process.env[name]);
}

const foo = getEnv('foo', String);
const bar = getEnv('bar', Number);
```

Here, `foo` is inferred as type `string`, and `bar` is inferred as type `number`.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I tried to build but the `cast: SimpleConstructor<T>` blew my mind.

Comment: Yeah, that is better 

Comment: I just noticed, whatever `string` value (process.env.* always is a `string`) I pass into `getEnv('foo', Boolean)`, it always returns `true`

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler the only string value for which it would be false is `""`, e.g. empty string. That's just how truthiness of strings works. If you want to account for certain string values like `"false"`, `"0"`, etc., you won't have quite as elegant a solution--you'd need to `Boolean(JSON.parse(process.env.*))` instead of just `Boolean(process.env.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Type assertions (the `as` keyword) just tell the compiler that you know the type of something better than the compiler, they provide no runtime functionality.
Moreover, types are erased at compile time, so you can't make decisions at runtime based on what `T` was passed to the function

One approach would be to pass in a a `string` denoting the conversion you want and have a switch in which you perform the respective conversion. Typescript can help you type the return type correctly based on the passed in string:

```
type SimpleTypeNames = "string" | "number" | "boolean"
type SimpleTypeNamesToType<T extends SimpleTypeNames> =  
    T extends "string" ? string :
    T extends "number" ? number :
    T extends "boolean" ? boolean :
    never

function getEnv<T extends SimpleTypeNames>(name: string, type: T): SimpleTypeNamesToType<T>
function getEnv(name: string, type: SimpleTypeNames): SimpleTypeNamesToType<SimpleTypeNames> 
{ 
    switch(type) {
        case "boolean" : return !!process.env[name];
        case "number" : return +process.env[name];
        case "string" : return process.env[name] + "";
    }
}

getEnv("b", "boolean") // return boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

`as` does not provide type conversion. As a matter of fact, `as` will be stripped off in the compiled JS. Its only usage is to clarify types when writing code, basically in cases where the developer knows more about types than TS's automatic type checking, example:

```
const foo = Math.random()<5 ? {bar:'42'} : {bar:42};
// TS thinks that 'foo: {bar: string} | {bar: number}'
// But the developer knows that 'foo: {bar: string}'
// 'as' can be used to prevent TS from throwing error when we know they won't happen:
const someString: string = foo.bar; // error
const someOtherString: string = (foo.bar as string); // no error
```

There is no actual cast in JS because there is no types at runtime - types only exist at compile time, in the "TS-layer". The JS-way to create an object of a certain type from another is [factory functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1).